# get value from jsonp using php

Tags: php

I have jsonp like below

```
jsonp([
{"id":"HK\/HKD","bid":"40.14700","ask":"40.24300","high":"40.19500","low":"0.00000","vol":"0.03"},
{"id":"AUD\/JPY","bid":"58.69800","ask":"58.78200","high":"58.74000"}])
```

I am trying to get data from it using json_decode but its not working fine for me. I want get value of

`HK/HKD called ask`

and

```
AUD/JPY called ask
```

But I am not able to get it. Let me know if anyone can help me for get it.
Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with json_decode ?

Comment: its showing blank, no any error.

Comment: Does the string you are trying to decode actually contain `jsonp(` at the start?

Comment: @NigelRen Yes sir, I have copy pasted response and its saying jsonp. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the extra `jsonp(` and the closing `)`, you would need to strip these off before decoding them.  Just use `substr()` to remove these before decoding them...

```
$json = 'jsonp([
{"id":"HK\/HKD","bid":"40.14700","ask":"40.24300","high":"40.19500","low":"0.00000","vol":"0.03"},
{"id":"AUD\/JPY","bid":"58.69800","ask":"58.78200","high":"58.74000"}])';

$json = substr($json, 6, strlen($json)-7);
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => HK/HKD
            [bid] => 40.14700
            [ask] => 40.24300
            [high] => 40.19500
            [low] => 0.00000
            [vol] => 0.03
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => AUD/JPY
            [bid] => 58.69800
            [ask] => 58.78200
            [high] => 58.74000
        )

)
```

Even better would be to try and have these parts removed at the source of the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $items = json_decode('[{"id":"HK\/HKD","bid":"40.14700","ask":"40.24300","high":"40.19500","low":"0.00000","vol":"0.03"},
  {"id":"AUD\/JPY","bid":"58.69800","ask":"58.78200","high":"58.74000"}]');

  foreach ($items as $item) {
  var_dump($item->id);
}
```

It works for me. Can you try this?